# Shopify - using if statements within js.liquid and scss.liquid files

Tags: javascript, css, sass, shopify, liquid

I am trying to merge JS files together in 1 file, however I need to set conditions using the if statements within the js file.

I have created file.js.liquid but it does not seem to working; I added a test for example:

```
{% if template contains 'index' %}
  console.log('homepage loaded');
{% endif %}
```

Example of what i am trying to do, of course have plenty i need to do.

```
{% if settings.the_simpsons_enabled and settings.simpsons_video_enable %}
  // video popup
  $(".video-popup").videoPopup();
{% endif %}
```

The conditional statements are also not working within scss.liquid files either:

```
{% if template contains 'index' or template contains 'collection' or template contains 'product' %}
  @import url("{{ 'owl.carousel.scss' | asset_url }}");
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas why if would not be working or if its even possible? I assume it is being a liquid file.

Comment: You can't use @import.

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate JS and minify/concatenate SASS with something like gulp?

Answer (score 1):

The Liquid extension on such files like CSS or JS allows use of Liquid variables but not statements.

So {{ write_my_liquid_var_here }} will work. {% if liquid_statement %}do something{% endif %} won't.

Comment: Seems a little pointless, im a shopify plus customer with a few sites as well so might speak with them and see if this can be added lol im trying to reduce the css / js file requests on the page as rather a few and with the apps the store has installed does not help.... google insights testing has a low score for mobile and desktop which is what i am trying to reduce you see.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding Shopify and SASS**

The following won't work as you can't use `@import` in Shopify's SASS files.

```
@import url("{{ 'owl.carousel.scss' | asset_url }}"); //This will not work
```

**Regarding using conditional liquid statements in .js.liquid files**

I don't know everything about this subject, but I do know the following two things.

1) Check out [this thread](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/js-liquid-file-if-statements-not-working-as-in-regular-liquid-files-239216) and you'll see that this type of statement won't work because js files are parsed independent of normal liquid templates, so it would have no idea which template you're viewing.

```
{% if template contains 'index' %} //This will not work
```

A better place to put the above logic would be at the bottom of your theme.liquid file above the `</body>` tag.  However this won't help you with what seems to be your goal of reducing HTTP requests by using one JavaScript fie.

2) However, *you can* access values in your settings_data.json file

```
{% if settings.the_simpsons_enabled and settings.simpsons_video_enable %} //This will work
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Just seen this, but actually the import did work.... but found it still loaded the css files on page load so was not solution i needed as i trying to reduce the amount of css and js files loads on page load as to many.... trying to speed the load time up a little and google insights page test have low scoring for desktop and mobile so also trying to improve those but finding it difficult with how limited shopify is and 3rd party apps the site also has installed lol

Comment: I am a shopify plus customer with a few sites as well so might speak with them and see if this can be added, i think one of their biggest customers so might be able to get this done lol im trying to reduce the css / js file requests on the page as rather a few and with the apps the store has installed does not help.... google insights testing has a low score for mobile and desktop which is what i am trying to reduce you see.

Comment: James, if part of your JavaScript requires the use of Shopify objects, like `template`, `product`, or `customer`, you can put these `<script>` in a normal liquid template.  When I want to access them, I place them at the end of `theme.liquid` and it works (That could possibly help reduce HTTP request, but might not be the best solution for large blocks of code)

Comment: Yep that is how it current is, including them but as you saw wont reduce the HTTP requests

Comment: This may not be the most elegant idea, but could you create a liquid snippet file consisting of all of the JS code in `<script>` tags and include it via liquid in your `theme.liquid` file?  This way, they would be combined at the server level.  It actually wouldn't be linking to an external script file and wouldn't clutter your `theme.liquid` template.